# Dumping the results into text file that has the same name as the variable

Tags: python, automation, python-3.5

I'm trying to write a code using `netmiko` that will execute few Show commands and save the results into text file with the name of variable (which is IP here).

For example if I insert IP 8.8.8.8  I want the results to be save into a text file with the name 8.8.8.8. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `print` returns `None`, and you're setting `pre_r` equal to that `print` call's return value:

```
pre_r = print(connection.send_command(command))
```

Instead, set `pre_r` equal to the data, and `print` that instead:

```
for command in commands:
    pre_r = connection.send_command(command)
    print(pre_r)

with open(SwIp, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pre_r)
```

You also may want to move that `for` loop inside the `with` statement:

```
with open(SwIp, 'wb') as f:
    f.writelines([connection.send_command(cmd) for cmd in commands])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `SwIp` variable appears to contain the IP address (as a string), you can do it by slightly changing how you `open()` the file.

```
with open(SwIp, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(str(pre_r)+'\n')
```

Note I added a trailing newline to the data written to the file and removed the unnecessary `f.close()` in your code (the `with` will do that for you automatically).